# How to read Google Analytics events data?

Tags: google-analytics, android, event-tracking

My question is about Android application button press tracking, but I believe there is no big difference with button press on the web page, so I ask the question here.

I would like to track user actions and user settings in my Android app, so I've added the following code (executed when user presses particular button):

```
if (user_name != "") has_name = 1;
...
easyTracker.send(MapBuilder.createEvent("ui_action", "send_mail", "has_name", (long) has_name).build());
easyTracker.send(MapBuilder.createEvent("ui_action", "send_mail", "has_address", (long) has_address).build());
easyTracker.send(MapBuilder.createEvent("ui_action", "send_mail", "has_operator", (long) has_operator).build());
easyTracker.send(MapBuilder.createEvent("ui_action", "send_mail", "has_passport", (long) has_passport).build());
easyTracker.send(MapBuilder.createEvent("ui_action", "send_mail", "has_phonenumber", (long) has_phonenumber).build());
easyTracker.send(MapBuilder.createEvent("ui_action", "send_mail", "has_mo_consent", (long) has_mo_consent).build());
easyTracker.send(MapBuilder.createEvent("ui_action", "send_mail", "has_other_docs", (long) has_other_docs).build());
easyTracker.send(MapBuilder.createEvent("ui_action", "send_mail", "has_screenshot", (long) has_screenshot).build());

easyTracker.send(MapBuilder.createEvent("ui_action", "complaint_region", email_to, null).build());
```

See [createEvent](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v3/events) description - it sends `Event category`, `Event action`, `Event label`, Event value accordingly.

Now I see the following results for particular date -

*EVENT ACTION: send_mail » EVENT CATEGORY: ui_action*

[image: ea:send_mail-ec:ui_action]

EVENT CATEGORY: ui_action » EVENT ACTION: complaint_region
[image: ec:ui_action_ea:complaint_region]

I can not understand - should not be total number of events `complaint_region` multiplied by 8 (number of event labels for `send_mail`) be equal to `send_mail` total events? `76*8 != 1038`.

And, the main question - how many times all users pressed the button `76`?

Answer (score 1):

The same events can be sent from multiple places.   Just because the "complaint_region" and "send_mail" events are sent together when this button is pressed, it doesn't mean that that is the case everywhere in the application.

If you are trying to count the number of users that press the button, you should look in the "unique events" column.   68 users triggered the "complaint_region" event with a few users doing so multiple times.

Because the "send_mail" events were each triggered by around 120 users, I expect that you will find that there is another button that can trigger those.